# Upgrading Apache Flink need to update pom.xml?

Tags: apache-flink

I've just upgraded my flink from version 1.9.1 to 1.11.2 (using docker)
I have already many flink jobs running in version 1.9.1
When I try to upgrade to 1.11.1 and re run my job, it shows error.

```
2020-11-12 06:49:17,731 WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn                              []

 - SASL configuration failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No JAAS configuration section named 'Client' was found in specified JAAS configuration file: '/tmp/jaas-1135609831848314731.conf'. Will continue connection to Zookeeper server without SASL authentication, if Zookeeper server allows it.
2020-11-12 06:49:17,739 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn                              [] - Opening socket connection to server xxxxxx:2181
2020-11-12 06:49:17,741 ERROR org.apache.curator.ConnectionState                           [] - Authentication failed
```

And this is the error after deploying my flink job:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API paths not defined

and also:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.api.common.state.OperatorStateStore.getSerializableListState(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/flink/api/common/state/ListState;

Do I need to change every pom for my flink jobs?
Is there any work around without changing my source code?

Thanks

Comment: It may be a good idea to post the error so you can be more specific.

Comment: There were changes in 1.10 and 1.11 that require minor adjustments in some cases. You could read the release notes: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/release-notes/flink-1.10.html and https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/release-notes/flink-1.11.html, or tell us what went wrong.

Comment: This is my pom: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
   <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
   <version>1.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
   <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11</artifactId>
   <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
   <version>1.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
  I assume it tries to find flink lib with version 1.9 while my new flink image only contain 1.11 lib jar

Comment: Please find below error detail: ERROR org.apache.curator.ConnectionState                           [] - Authentication failed 06:58:18.839 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.taskexecutor.TaskExecutor - Registration at ResourceManager failed due to an error
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.exceptions.FencingTokenException: Fencing token not set: Ignoring message And also : Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API paths not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you do have to rebuild your Flink jobs whenever you update the Flink version being used to run them. The libraries you use should be from the same exact version used by the Job Manager and Task Managers.

If you are trying to automate deployments for a CI/CD pipeline, you could inject the version number into the pom.xml using an environment variable -- but doing things like that can make it hard to debug when things go wrong.

Comment: Too bad, bcs flink version keep upgrading. Anyway thanks for your response Dave